# Whats going on in this x86 ASM code puzzle?

Tags: assembly, x86

This is a bit of a puzzle that I have picked up, but being quite new to x86 asm I don't really understand a whole lot of it.

It appears as though we are building up a string on the stack and then calling a syscall to do something with it?

If anyone could explain a bit more what is going on in the code, that would be helpful.

```
mov eax, 0xaf7a9e11           Move 0xaf7a9e11 into eax register.
xor eax, esi                  XOR eax with esi (should be empty?) into eax
push eax                      Push eax onto the stack
mov eax, 0xc6749612
xor eax, esi
push eax
...
Lots more instances where we mov xor and push.
...
xor eax, eax                  XOR eax with itself (essentially inverting it?)
mov ebx, eax
inc ebx
add al, 4
mov ecx, esp
push 52
pop edx
int 0x80                      Call the interrupt handler for syscall 52?
```

Comment: `exc` is an obvious typo.  Did you type this manual instead of copy/paste?

Comment: Yep, that was a typo, fixed. Yes this code was transcribed, it was handed to me on a flyer.

Comment: im guessing an encryption/decryption is happening particularly in the xor and push, and its building the data (string?)in the stack. i think its a shellcode.

Answer (score 0):

The push stuff looks like de-obfuscating an immediate string with an XOR key in `esi`.  This kind of thing makes it harder to find ASCII strings with `strings(1)` on the binary, but is to weak to really be called encryption.

---

On Linux, `int 0x80` with `eax = 4` is [`ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).  The args are:

- fd = `ebx=1`: stdout is FD 1
- buf = `ecx=esp`: the buffer of data we just pushed
- count = `edx=52`: 52 bytes.

So it writes 52 bytes of data that was stored as immediate operands in the instruction stream.  I assume you can understand how those values got there, and are just looking for the why / what happens.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for tons of stuff, including the Linux system call ABI and reference manuals.

---

> `XOR eax with esi (should be empty?)`

Register can't be empty.  They always hold 32 bits.  They can be zero, though.  Many of those hex bytes look like they're in the printable ASCII range, so probably this prints a human-readable string to stdout.

If that's really the entry point, then Linux does provide an initial process state with zeroed registers.  The ABI says they're undefined (and that's the case after the dynamic linker runs), but Linux avoid leaking kernel data by zeroing registers after execve.